# DoCmd.TransferSharePointList not linking all columns

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba, ms-access-2010

My database that I distribute to my team is failing to sync all columns on a linked  SharePoint list

I've added a button to the database to auto re link the SharePoint to try resolve this issue:

```
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "tblPro"
DoEvents

DoCmd.TransferSharePointList _
acLinkSharePointList, _
"https://nhsengland-my.sharepoint.com/personal/blahblah/", _
"{C4ZFF04B-5FE8-4C35-AAE7-2503FC532EC0}", _
"{4254C6B8-2582-4AF5-9A93-39914A02E379}", _
"tblPro", _
True

CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblPro").RefreshLink
DoEvents
```

Although this links the SharePointlist it does not sync all columns, e.g. only syncs 8 out 10 columns making the data not available.

just to clarify the columns are not hidden.

The only way to fix this is to re-link it manually which is a **no no**...is there anyway to force access to get all columns using a procedure?

Many thanks
Max

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because is linking all the columns found in the view you specified. This is available also for filters. Change specified view and try again. A good idea is to delete cached objects by compressing the database before because.